# RadGrid do Telerik perde paginação ao exportar para Excel

Tags: javascript, c#, asp, telerik

Quando faço exportação do RadGrid do Telerik para Excel, a RadGrid quando possui muitos registros, perde a paginação. Tentei resolver com rebind, mas não funcionou. Alguém teria alguma ideia?

Em anexo as telas do antes e após a exportação para excel.[image: Antes de exportar:]
Após exportar para excel e clicar em uma das paginações. As paginações somem.

[image: Após exportar para excel.]

Antes de tentar a solução com rebind, era mais frequente isso ocorrer, agora ocorre com mais frequência, às vezes não ocorre. 
Além disso, quando clico nas outras abas, que também contem grids com registros, quando vou exportar para o excel, e dou o rebind, ele volta para a aba principal.

Gostaria também de saber como faço para manter-me na mesma aba em que exportei os registros para excel. Quando estou na aba principal, as demais abas ficam ativas somente quando seleciono uma linha, então elas carregam com a informação da linha. Entretanto, após o rebind, essas informações das outras abas se perdem.

Código em C#:

```
private void ClickToolbar(short value)
    {
        this.ExportSettings.HideStructureColumns = true;
        this.ExportSettings.FileName = string.Concat(this.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageTitle, " - Exportação");

        this.MasterTableView.HierarchyDefaultExpanded = false;
        this.MasterTableView.HierarchyLoadMode = GridChildLoadMode.ServerOnDemand;

        if (this.MasterTableView.HasDetailTables)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Count; i++)
            {
                this.MasterTableView.DetailTables[i].HierarchyDefaultExpanded = false;
                this.MasterTableView.DetailTables[i].HierarchyLoadMode = GridChildLoadMode.ServerOnDemand;

            }
        }

        GridTableView backupMasterTableView = this.MasterTableView.Clone();

        switch (value)
        {
            case 0:
                GridSettingsPersister savePersister = new GridSettingsPersister(this);
                object[] parameters = new object[] { this.IdGridConfiguracao, savePersister.SaveSettings() };
                this.Page.GetType().GetMethod("SalvarConfiguracaoGrid").Invoke(this.Page, parameters);

                if (RebindOnClickSaveToolbar)
                    this.Rebind();
                break;
            case 2:
                exporting = true;
                PrepareToPrintGrid();
                this.MasterTableView.ExportToPdf();
                break;
            case 4:
                #region Formato do Excel


                this.ExportSettings.Excel.Format = Telerik.Web.UI.GridExcelExportFormat.Biff;
                #endregion

                PrepareToPrintGrid();
                exporting = true;
                this.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
                this.MasterTableView.Rebind();

                break;
        }

        if (exporting)
        {
            this.MasterTableView.HeaderStyle.Wrap = backupMasterTableView.HeaderStyle.Wrap;
            this.MasterTableView.ItemStyle.Wrap = backupMasterTableView.ItemStyle.Wrap;
            this.MasterTableView.Font.Size = backupMasterTableView.Font.Size;
            this.MasterTableView.Font.Name = backupMasterTableView.Font.Name;
            this.MasterTableView.Style["vertical-align"] = backupMasterTableView.Style["vertical-align"];
            this.MasterTableView.Style["text-align"] = backupMasterTableView.Style["text-align"];
            this.MasterTableView.UseAllDataFields = backupMasterTableView.UseAllDataFields;
            this.MasterTableView.HierarchyDefaultExpanded = backupMasterTableView.HierarchyDefaultExpanded;
            this.MasterTableView.HierarchyLoadMode = backupMasterTableView.HierarchyLoadMode;

            this.MasterTableView.PageSize = backupMasterTableView.PageSize;
            this.MasterTableView.AllowPaging = backupMasterTableView.AllowPaging;

        }
    }

protected void PrepareToPrintGrid()
    {
        #region Seleciona o tamanho do papel
        // Change to legal paper for high column counts
        if (this.MasterTableView.Columns.Count > 8)
        {
            this.ExportSettings.Pdf.PaperSize = GridPaperSize.Legal;
        }
        // Change to portrait if many columns
        if (this.MasterTableView.Columns.Count > 3)
        {
            Unit swapUnit = this.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageWidth;
            this.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageWidth = this.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageHeight;
            this.ExportSettings.Pdf.PageHeight = swapUnit;
            this.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
            this.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Estilos
        this.ExportSettings.Pdf.DefaultFontFamily = "Segoe UI";
        this.MasterTableView.HeaderStyle.Wrap = true;
        this.MasterTableView.ItemStyle.Wrap = true;
        this.MasterTableView.Font.Size = 8;
        this.MasterTableView.Font.Name = "Segoe UI";
        this.MasterTableView.Style["vertical-align"] = "middle";
        this.MasterTableView.Style["text-align"] = "left";
        #endregion

        //this.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
        this.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = true;
        this.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = true;
        this.MasterTableView.UseAllDataFields = true;

        #region Expande Detailstable
        this.MasterTableView.HierarchyDefaultExpanded = true;
        this.MasterTableView.HierarchyLoadMode = GridChildLoadMode.Client;

        if (this.MasterTableView.HasDetailTables)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Count; i++)
            {
                this.MasterTableView.DetailTables[i].HierarchyLoadMode = GridChildLoadMode.Client;
                this.MasterTableView.DetailTables[i].HierarchyDefaultExpanded = true;

            }
            this.MasterTableView.HierarchyDefaultExpanded = true;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Código em javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_toolbar_excel', function (e) {
    setTimeout(function () { preventTableBreakPager() }, 5000);
})

function preventTableBreakPager()
{
var gridVeiculosList = $find(gridVeiculos).get_masterTableView();
gridVeiculosList.rebind();
}
```

Comment: Não entendi... Não está plotando toda a informação para o Excel quando há muitos registros? Ou você espera que o Excel implemente a paginação? Apresente o código...

Comment: Ele salva direitinho. Só que a paginação da grid se perde. Quando clico no botão para exportar, consigo salvar com todas as informações. Mas após esse procedimento, quando clico em um uma das paginações, o grid se perde, fica apenas uma paginação. Fiz várias alterações, antes ficava uma paginação longa com todos os registros, agora só fica uma com poucos registros. Vou postar dois prints de antes e após a exportação para excel.

Comment: E o código do método que exporta, onde está?

Comment: Postei ali acima.

Answer (score 1):

A sua função Javascript `preventTableBreakPager` não precisa ser chamada no Click do botão, pois a Grid não precisa ser atualizada.

Tive o mesmo problema com a exportação para Excel do Telerik no passado. A solução foi cancelar a atualização da Grid usando evento **OnRequestStart** do componente **RadAjaxManager**.

Você precisa declarar o **RadAjaxManager** na sua **Page** ou **MasterPage**. Provavelmente você já esteja utilizando este componente:

```
 <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
     <AjaxSettings>
         <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btn_toolbar_excel">
             <UpdatedControls>
                 <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="gridVeiculos" />
             </UpdatedControls>
         </telerik:AjaxSetting>
     </AjaxSettings>
 </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

Precisa adicionar este código no evento **Load** da página:

```c#
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      var ajaxManager = RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(this);
      if (ajaxManager != null)
      {
          // Está função está no arquivo Public.js
          ajaxManager.ClientEvents.OnRequestStart = "radAjaxManager_requestStart";
      }
   }
}
```

E por fim, precisa adicionar este código Javascript:

```js
function radAjaxManager_requestStart(sender, args) {

    // Cancela a atualização do Ajax durante a exportação para Excel
    if (args.get_eventTargetElement().id.indexOf("btn_toolbar_excel") >= 0) {
        args.set_enableAjax(false);
    }
}
```